# Как подсчитать количество знаков препинания в текстовом файле

Tags: c++, файлы, текст

Собственно, я пытался, но не вышло:

```
int kol_znakov(const char* name)
    {
        char s[100]; FILE* f;
        int kol = 0; //переменная для количества знаков препинания в файле
        f = fopen(name, "rt");
        if (f == NULL) { cout << "Cannot open file\n"; return 0; }
        while (fgets(s, 100, f)) {
            if (ispunct(*s))
            {
                kol++;
            }

        }
        fclose(f);
            return kol;
    }
```

Оно считает только строки, состоящие из знаков препинания, а это совсем не то, что мне нужно. Помогите найти решение этой задачи, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После считывания из файла `fgets(s, 100, f)` вы проверяете только первый символ (`*s`).

Необходимо пройтись по всей считанной строке и посчитать количество знаков пунктуации:

```
while (fgets(s, 100, f)) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (ispunct(s[i]))
            kol++
}
```

---

В языке с++ используйте стандартные файловые потоки [fstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream) вместо `FILE` и т.д.

Comment: *Видимо, зря я пошёл учиться на программиста* -- хорошо, если это понимают сразу. Но, уверяю, в любой другой области лёгких путей не бывает, и с подобными вещами (изучением букваря) придётся сталкиваться. Даже подметая двор в оранжевой жилетке.

Answer (score 0):

Решение при помощи регулярных выражений

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str, allText;
    ifstream inFile;        // объект для обработки файлового ввода
    inFile.open("1.txt");   // ассоциировать inFile с файлом
    getline(inFile, allText);

    while (inFile.good())   // пока ввод успешен и не достигнут EOF
    {
        getline(inFile, str);
        allText += str;
    }
    inFile.close(); // завершить работу с файлом
    cmatch result;
    // символы пунктуации: ! % ^ & * ( ) – + = { } | ~ [ ] \ ; ' : " < > ? , . / #
    regex words_regex("[!%^&*()–+={}|~\\[\\]\\;':\"\\<\\>\\?\\,\\.\\/\\#]");    

    auto words_begin = sregex_iterator(allText.begin(), allText.end(), words_regex);
    auto words_end = sregex_iterator();

    cout << "Found: " << distance(words_begin, words_end) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```